# Start FF with plugins disabled

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, plugins

Strange problem. Opened FF 3.6.3 after a re-boot and my last opened tabs appeared but none of the page or menu elements would respond to a click. No error messages...just locked up. Started FF with a different profile and it works normally.

Next I used FEBE to restore a backup of my working profile and, after the restore, it's doing the same thing - locked out.

No newly installed plugins but since a brand new profile works while a restored one doesn't it kinda points to a problematic plug-in. Is there any way to start FF with all plugins disabled?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you start Firefox in [Safe Mode](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Safe+Mode)?  In a terminal run:

```
firefox -safe-mode
```

Or specify the profile to open:

```
firefox -safe-mode -P profilename
```

Comment: This could be for Windows as well...

Comment: @nitro: AFAIK the Firefox commandline options are pretty well synchronized across the various OS's.  this should work for any platform.  "terminal" just refers to anywhere you'd input a commandline, including the Windows Start-Menu -> Run... dialog.